# Using the Take Method on my model Substitute Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically I want to have a way to select the number in my

```
foreach(var sheet in Model.Sheets.Take(100))
{
...
}
```

I would like the user to be able to specify this value and reload the page using the take method, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass a parameter in to your controller?

```
public ActionResult Index(int? toTake)
{
    foreach(var sheet in Model.Sheets.Take(toTake != null ? toTake.Value : 100))
    {
    }

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is in your View, you're doing it wrong.

Do this `.Take()` bit in your controller actions and pass along an `IEnumerable<T>` to your view.

For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? pageSize)
{
    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();

    foreach(var sheet in Model.Sheets.Take(pageSize != null ? pageSize : 20))
    {
        //yada yada yada. Do something here with sheet and model.
    }

    return View(model);
}
```